# In Map progaram I got error as Failed to install map.apk on device 'emulator-5554

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary

I did everything properly,  by useingdebug.keystore I generated my MD% code and I got my Valid API key from google website and I gave permission for using internet connection in MasinFest.xmland used my mapping key value in main.xml.and in MapActivity File I simply used this below code

```
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MapsActivity extends MapActivity 
{    
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am using Android 4.0.3 version and Google API Level 15, I am Getting Error as 05-22 10:32:42.086: E/MapActivity(656): Couldn't get connection factory client in LogCat.. Help me regarding this please.. Thanks in Advance

Comment: I m trying this in emulator not on physical android phone, so what i do here. how to install google map in this.. help me in this. 
 
I am getting Output in emulator as google page but it shows simply blank page,not getting map .

Answer (score 0):

well you are trying to import the classes of google maps. for that purpose you need to be sure that google maps app is already installed on the device you are trying to work on. unless it finds google maps application on your device your application wont work.

Comment: I m trying this in emulator not on physical android phone, so what i do here. how to install google map in this.. help me in this

Comment: I am getting Output in emulator as google page but it shows simply blank page,not getting map

Comment: here i m not using geolocation and all.. i m trying to display google map. i didnt use any zoom , geolocation, location and all.. so for this y i have to try this in android and also i dont have android device, so give solution for my issue

Comment: in that page i m not able to get solution ..its seems not possible to install android map in emulator..then how u viewing map in emulator..

Comment: I got map , thanks for ur suggestion .. i missed to give permission inmainfeast.xml, while i checked ma code, i saw that.. thank u ..